# How can I push to another view after user finishes taking photo using UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to allow the user to take a photo using UIImagePickerController and after finishing take him to a UITableView, passing the chosen image, where he can add info about the photo in text fields such as description.

Right now this is my code in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:

```
if (image) {
     PhotoInfoViewController* photo_info_controller = [[PhotoInfoViewController alloc] init];
    photo_info_controller.image = image;


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.parentViewController presentViewController:photo_info_controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

This takes the code to the next view which is a static tableviewcontroller[image]

and in the PhotoInfoView controller

I see that viewDidLoad gets called by NSLog but all I see is an empty tableViewController and no text fields...

Any one have any advice??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change PhotoInfoViewController initialization.

1. Set storyboard id in your storyboard file to PhotoInfoViewController
2. Change code.

> ```
> UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:<#name of storyboard#> bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
> PhotoInfoViewController *photo_info_controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoInfoViewController"];
> ```